# Recaptcha timeouts on some browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, react-google-recaptcha

Using [react-google-recaptcha-v3](https://github.com/t49tran/react-google-recaptcha-v3/) executing

```
await executeRecaptcha("contact");
```

timeouts on some browsers.
I am not sure if the root cause is within the repo ([issue](https://github.com/t49tran/react-google-recaptcha-v3/issues/39)) or upstream, as it only fails in some browser configurations.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? Thanks